# Segment 3D mesh and extract mesh vertices and landmarks for each segment

Tags: r, 3d, visualization, mesh, rgl

Here is my 3D facial mesh and landmarks available from [here](https://github.com/Patricklv/Segment-facial-mesh):

```
library(Rvcg)
library(rgl)
library(Morpho) #read.fcsv

mymesh <- vcgPlyRead("C:\\Users\\Patrick Wen\\Desktop\\mymesh.ply")
shade3d(mymesh, col="lightgrey", specular = "#202020", alpha = 0.7)

mylm <- read.fcsv("C:\\Users\\Patrick Wen\\Desktop\\mylm.fcsv")

plot3d(mylm, type = "s", col = "red", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "z", 
       size = 0.4, aspect = FALSE, alpha = 0.8, add=T)
```

[image]

I wish to segment the human face into several mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive regions (like figure below) and extract vertices associated with each module as well as landmarks (red dots) belonging to each module.
[image]

This is an illustration of segmentation of the human face into several regions. Additionally, the border of some regions might be curved rather than straight. So it is inappropriate to extract vertices/landmarks by finding all points whose x and y coordinates were within a certain range. I am not sure if this could be realized in R. Any idea on any other software that is capable of doing what I want?

Comment: What are your definitions for the various segments?

Comment: I wish to draw some boundary lines in the first place. It seems this should be done in some software. I tried in MeshLab but failed. I have the feeling that some 3D software should work to identify vertices and R may be useful for grouping the red landmarks. But I really have no idea how to implement this line of thinking.

Comment: The `rgl` package lets you select square regions using `select3d`.  If you want to work at a lower level you can create your own mouse handler.  So it would be possible to write a function to select irregular regions by mouse, but I don't know of one that already exists.  Maybe look at packages that use `rgl` in `Shiny`?

Comment: @Patrickhow did you do the pose estimation (the red points)?